# Where Should My Feedback & Bug Reports Related To Stack Overflow For Teams Be Posted?

Tags: support, bug-reporting-process, stack-overflow-for-teams, feature-request-process

So, you're <strike>a glutton for punishment</strike> one of our highly appreciated and eagerly anticipated early users for Stack Overflow For Teams, and you've got some feedback or a bug report for us to see? Here's a quick rundown of the best places to send different kinds of feedback.

Most importantly, ***you're our hero and we want you to do whatever is most convenient for you***. Seriously, we really appreciate you working with us to make Stack Overflow For Teams as awesome as it can be, and it's totally on *us* to get feedback anywhere you'd like to provide it. There are also cases where, due to bugs or other unforeseen issues,  you might not be able to communicate via a suggested channel - that's totally fine. These are just some guidelines to help ensure the right folks see what you've said as soon as possible, so that we can act on it accordingly.

#### I have feedback or an issue that requires some of my organization's sensitive information for context.

Skip everything else below and just have your team administrator e-mail us directly. They should have received some contact information when the team was set up, if that's not the case or it can't be found, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we'll make sure they reach out to you as quickly as possible.

#### I have some general feedback or a feature request

Feel free to post here on Meta Stack Overflow, use the [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) tag along with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as warranted. ***Be careful to not post sensitive information***, if you accidentally do this, edit it out, and [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to let us know it needs redacting.

You can also e-mail us directly if you'd rather not post publicly.

#### I have a bug report or need support.

For now, we're asking that folks e-mail us directly with any bugs so that we're *certain* that they're seen by the correct people and addressed quickly. We might want to hold off on a build, or something else, depending on the nature of a bug report and e-mail is the best way to make sure we see it quickly.

#### I saw a bug report or feedback posted in the wrong place.

Please leave it, ping one of us in chat if you feel like it, but we're monitoring both MSE and MSO and will make sure it gets to the right place.

#### Why treat this any different than Jobs?

Because it's a rapid moving target with several teams working on things at once (due to the fact that Stack Overflow For Teams touches quite a few things). Once it settles down a bit, we'll *ideally* have integral support making the point rather moot. While Meta is a great place for handling stuff relating to public Q&A, it's not exceptionally great for handling non-public stuff, up-to and including folks not wanting to associate themselves with using certain products publicly.

Hence, in that respect, Jobs needs to (eventually) have a more enterprise-y-ish support and bug reporting thingadongdong attached to it as well. We're looking at that over the long term while keeping in mind that private stuff is often going to overlap with public stuff too, which makes it interesting.

Questions? Let us know. Thanks again for helping us test teams, and even if you're not actively testing but just helping folks find the best information to help them, we really do appreciate you. This (hopefully) provides an easy path that doesn't create more confusion than it solves, and we'll update this once we've got something better in place after we get some dust settled.

Comment: "ping one of us in chat", which chat room would that be? Is there a specific chat for teams? (like there was one for the Mentorship project)

Comment: "For now, we're asking that folks e-mail us directly with any bugs" That's nice, but it would help if you included the email address you would like us to use :)

Comment: @DavidPostill You should have gotten that info (or it's quite possibly the person that emailed you to say your team is ready), if you're really stuck there, use the contact form, and we'll make sure the right person reaches out to you asap

Comment: @BhargavRao No defined room, but we're generally in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Again, it's purely optional and opportunistic, please don't go out of your way to find someone, we'll find the post within a day or so and get it where it needs to go.

Comment: Shouldn't each of these headers and subsequent sections be split out into answers? That way they can be expanded/edited independently as necessary and can be linked directly.