# Impact section for SO Teams doesn't show number of users reached as it does for Public Q&A

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, people-reached

On all our sites on our profile page the **Impact** of our efforts shows the number of people reached, even if it's very few. On our Teams' profiles our impact section doesn't show this information:

[image: Impact for Teams and Public Q&A]

PS: This probably affects all teams and is not private, [I'm posting here along with a mention in The Tavern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/where-should-my-feedback-bug-reports-related-to-stack-overflow-for-teams-be-po) as it's easy to upload the image, respond to questions, and show that this has been reported. <- It was luck that I spotted that you are expected to email or shout-out Teams Support or Bugs, while searching for dupes.

Comment: Seems like by-design to me

Comment: @SamuelLiew definitely needs a formatting tweak though.

Comment: @SamuelLiew What leads you to that conclusion, the inconsistency or the white space (something else)?

Comment: @TheWanderer Well, that's part of what we're working on and why Donna asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings). :) We need to fix profiles for Teams - in addition to making them responsive. It's in progress.

Comment: Mostly by design, as Samuel Liew said.